# docker chained command in centOS terminal

Tags: docker, docker-compose, centos

I am trying to a run a chained command on my container in order to update the command.

This is my command:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint java -jar /home/dev/juju-1.0.0.jar -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8080 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8080 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost ng-juju-prod
```

The problem is I keep getting this error:

unknown shorthand flag: 'j' in -jar

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime) have a different syntax for running entrypoints with multiple args. Have you tried `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash IMAGE_NAME -c java -jar ...`?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to override a container's entrypoint with a longer command, the `docker run --entrypoint` option takes only the first word of the command (the binary to run); if you have further options they need to get passed after the image name.

```sh
docker run                       \
  -it                            \ # for programs that interact on the console
  --entrypoint java              \ # override image ENTRYPOINT
  ng-juju-prod                   \ # image name
  -jar /home/dev/juju-1.0.jar ...  # arguments to entrypoint (CMD)
```

This construct can be kind of awkward.  If you change your image's `ENTRYPOINT` line to be `CMD`

```sh
CMD ["java", "-jar", "juju-1.0.jar"] # not ENTRYPOINT
```

then you can provide the entire command after the image name, without a `--entrypoint` option

```sh
docker run -it ng-juju-prod \
  java -jar /home/dev/juju-1.0.jar ...
```

Another [pattern](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint) you run into is to use `ENTRYPOINT` for a complete command and `CMD` for its options.  Anything after the `docker run` image name replaces the `CMD`, but leaves the `ENTRYPOINT` intact.

```sh
# must be JSON-array form; must include the program name and not
# just the interpreter
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/home/dev/juju-1.0.jar"]
# must be JSON-array form, or absent
CMD ["-Dconfiguration.default=true"]
```

```sh
docker run -it ng-juju-prod \             # no --entrypoint
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true ... # options only
```